# How do I run a WAR on Tomcat within eclipse if it's not a 'dynamic web app'?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am going through the jwt tutorial (this is Java Web Toolkit, not JSON Web Tokens). The tutorial provides an eclipse project to download and import into eclipse, and has instructions for deploying it on a jetty server.

I would like to deploy it on the tomcat server I already have installed as a server in eclipse, so that I can make changes and redeploy without the annoying steps of copying the WAR file to an external Tomcat install and attaching a remote debug session.

I've built the war file, and if I deploy it to the external session it runs fine. But I cannot figure out how to tell eclipse to deploy it to the internal server. When I right-click the project and choose "Run" or "Debug", there is an option for running it as an application, but none for running on a server. I am guessing that eclipse only provides that option for "Dynamic Web Applications", but this isn't marked that way, and that's just a guess.

How can I configure the project so that eclipse will know to deploy its war file on the internal server?

Also -- it's not a Maven project, they have a build.xml for Ant.

---

Well, I found "Project Facets" and set the project facet for my 'hello' application to be "Dynamic Web Module", and now there's an option for running it on the server. But when I do, I get 404 "did not find a representation for the current resource", with no error messages in the console or the terminal. I retried the WAR in the external server just to make sure, and that still works.

Any suggestions?

---

Link to tutorial: it's section 3 of https://www.webtoolkit.eu/jwt/latest/doc/userguide/userguide.html

I realize Dynamic Web Module may have been the wrong path, but in our age of trial-and-error programming, it seemed reasonable to try to make eclipse think it was a web project for this purpose. I'm happy to back that out (somehow) if it isn't right.

Their instructions cover deployment within eclipse for Jetty, which I do not use.  I would have thought that, if an index.html or a web.xml were required for tomcat-under-eclipse, it would be required for Jetty-under-eclipse, but that's just a guess.

Comment: [1] Update your post with a link to the tutorial. [2] I understand why you tried adding the *Dynamic Web Module* facet, but that may have sent you down an unwanted path. The 404 may be because you have no **index.html**, nor deployment descriptor (**web.xml** with a welcome-file-list or servlet-mapping for your "web" project). [3] Does looking at how the project is successfully configured on the external Tomcat server reveal anything? I realize all you did was deploy the app, but maybe Tomcat then did something special for your JWT app after that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run **jwt-hello** on Tomcat within Eclipse after making the following configuration changes:

- Check **Properties > Project Facet > Dynamic Web Module**, setting version to **2.5** (so that the project was eligible to be added to Tomcat). I had problems using versions **3.0** and **4.0**.
- Set **Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level** to **1.8**.
- Set **Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > JRE System Library** to use JDK 1.8.
- Set **Properties > Web Project Settings > Context root** to **hello**, since it is **jwt-hello** by default.
- Copy **jwt-3.3.11.jar** from the **dist** folder of the downloaded JWt zip file to **WEB-INF/lib**.
- Copy **slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar**, **slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar** and **commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar** from the **lib** folder of the downloaded JWt zip file to **WEB-INF/lib**.

After configuring the project, create **WEB-INF/web.xml** with the content shown below to avoid the 404 problem, and then **build.xml > Run As > Ant Build** to build the project.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>GreetingServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>eu.webtoolkit.jwt.examples.hello.HelloMain</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>GreetingServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

On Eclipse's Tomcat server:

- Add the following line to **server.xml** to reflect the context root being changed from *jwt-hello* to *hello*:

  ```
  <Context docBase="jwt-hello" path="/hello" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:jwt-hello"/>
  ```
- Add the **jwt-hello** project to Tomcat and start it. The app works, with no errors or exceptions in the log:

  [image: Localhost web app]

Notes:

- I only realized afterwards that **jwt-hello** has a **WebRoot** folder with the required **lib** files, and a sample **web.xml** for Tomcat. It differed from the one I independently created, but I didn't research any further.
- My environment: Eclipse Photon + JDK 8u152 + Tomcat 9.0.10 + **jwt-3.3.11-rc1.zip** on Windows 10.
- I used **JDK 8** due to unrelated issues with getting Tomcat 9 to work with **JDK 10**.